# ListView with BindingList as ItemsSource not updated on remove

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a `ListView` bound to a `BindingList`.

Some elements of the `ItemTemplate` are depending on other records. When I remove an object from the `BindingList` the corresponding section in the `ListView` is deleted as it should **BUT** the `TextBoxes` of the remaining `List` elements are not updated.

I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and this works fine as long as values of bound `properties` are modified. But when as stated the whole object is removed from the `BindingList` the `properties` of the remaining elements in the `BindingList` have to be refreshed in the `ListView` - but this doesn't happen !

I hope I was clear enough and would be very thankfull for any help !

Best regards, 
Fabianus

Comment: take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Without code we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not provide any code, but let me give general solution.

The old issue; "ObservableCollection updated but its contained item did not" can be easily fixed by using `ObservableCollectionEx` nuget package.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObservableCollectionEx/

It is an implementation to wire up inner item changes to be exposed as you did, but I recommend you to reply on *already-made wheels*.